# Variable declared interchangebly has the same pattern of memory address

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I have a function and in the function, I have two variables,

```
  int auth_flag = 0;
  char buffer[16];
```

Now here is the output of gdb command `x/s buffer`

```
0xffffd01c: "\201\203\004\b\344\203\373\367\002"
```

and the output of `print &auth_flag`

```
$1 = (int *) 0xffffd018
```

Now , we see from the output that, location of auth_flag is 4 bytes before buffer. Now, If I declare the variables like this

```
char buffer[16];
int auth_flag = 0;
```

the output of the previous commands are

```
0xffffd00c: "\201\203\004\b\344\203\373\367\002" and
$1 = (int *) 0xffffd008
```

The same thing. 100 bytes behind but the order is same. My qs is, As I have reversed the variable declaration, Why didn't in gcc the address order of the variable is reversed. I am reading a book where it is said that the address ought to be reversed, But it isn't happening in my pc. So I am really confused.

Comment: Force no optimizations maybe? `#pragma OPTIMIZE OFF`

Comment: @Leonardo:  An exceptionally awful idea.  Even if it works in this one case, it's highly misleading, as the language makes no guarantees about where the compiler allocates automatic variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burn that book if it says that automatic variables have any particular address relationship to each other in standard C or C++.  Fields in a `struct` or `class` have an implementation defined layout.  Automatic variables aren't even guaranteed to be allocated to memory.

Now, what C++ *does* guarantee is the order in which symbols become defined (a compile time construct, not a memory layout issue), and what order constructors get invoked in.  For example, that order defines what the following code means in a precise manner:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    int y = x;  // this sees the argument x
    int x = 3;  // this defines an automatic variable named x that shadows the argument

    return x + y;
}
```

C++ also places guarantees on the order of construction and destruction for objects.  (Constructed when they come into scope in order of appearance, destructed in reverse order of construction as they leave scope.)  But, I won't dig deeply into that, since that goes beyond your question.

Comment: This variables are in a function.

Comment: Variables local to a function are automatic variables.  They are typically (but not always) allocated on a stack.  The only guarantee the language makes is that it automatically allocates them for you when they come into scope and automatically deletes them for you when they go out of scope.

Comment: Judging by your variable names, you wouldn't happen to be practicing writing a buffer overflow, would you? ;-)

Comment: So, How the stack of the function is defined then? If automatic variables aren't garanteed to be allocated, what happen's when the function is pushed into the stack, the variables should be allocated memory then. In which order they are allocated?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it is.. I am practicing a buffer_overflow :D

Comment: That is entirely up to the compiler writer's discretion.  Compilers are free to allocate local variables to registers.  On some platforms, called functions are required to preserve registers across calls.  So, flags such as `auth_flag` in your example might get allocated to a register and stay there and never appear on the stack.  It all depends on the compiler algorithms and the platform.

Comment: Thanx Joe Z for the ans, It seems these techniques are outdated now.

Comment: At the very least, they're going to be very specific to whatever program you're trying to exploit, and by that, I mean the specific binary executable.