# Why do variables declared with the same name in different scopes get assigned the same memory addresses?

Tags: c

I know that declaring a `char[]` variable in a while loop is scoped, having seen this post: [Redeclaring variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993585/redeclaring-variables-in-c).

Going through a tutorial on creating a simple web server in `C`, I'm finding that I have to manually clear memory assigned to `responseData` in the example below, otherwise the contents of `index.html` are just continuously appended to the response and the response contains duplicated contents from `index.html`:

```
while (1)
{
  int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
  char httpResponse[8000] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n";
  FILE *htmlData = fopen("index.html", "r");
  char line[100];
  char responseData[8000];
  while(fgets(line, 100, htmlData) != 0)
  {
      strcat(responseData, line);
  }
  strcat(httpResponse, responseData);
  send(clientSocket, httpResponse, sizeof(httpResponse), 0);
  close(clientSocket);
}
```

Correct by:

```
while (1)
{
  ...
  char responseData[8000];
  memset(responseData, 0, strlen(responseData));
  ...
}
```

Coming from JavaScript, this was surprising. Why would I want to declare a variable and have access to the memory contents of a variable declared in a different scope with the same name? Why wouldn't `C` just reset that memory behind the scenes?

Also... Why is it that variables of the same name declared in different scopes get assigned the same memory addresses?

According to this question: [Variable declared interchangebly has the same pattern of memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184202/variable-declared-interchangebly-has-the-same-pattern-of-memory-address) that ISN'T the case. However, I'm finding that this is occurring pretty reliably.

Comment: This memory has an *automatic* storage class. Such a storage class does not get initialized. So it can have any values in the beginning (including the ones that were there in the previous iteration). Why? Because it is defined this way and it gives the compiler (and the compiled code) the freedom of not doing some work which might be unnecessary.

Comment: If you do not like it - use Java. It is just coincidence that newly allocated on the stack variable share the same memory location.

Comment: It's a waste of CPU cycles to force every variable to be initialized to zero when it isn't needed.

Comment: Perhaps I should have worded that in a slightly less judgmental way @P__J__. Edited

Comment: @P__J__- you might be interested to know that there is an error on your webpage (diymat.co.uk): "Warning: Parameter 2 to wp_hide_post_Public::query_posts_join() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/vhosts/diymat.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286"

Comment: fair enough ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If you're always going to use `responseData` as a *string* you can keep 7999 bytes uninitialized and simply assign `'\0'` to the first one: `char responseData[8000]; *responseData = 0;`

Comment: Why would that result in the memory being cleared/reinitialized @pmg?

Comment: .. or if you want to initialize it (like with initializer) you can do `char responseData[8000] = {0};`. Under the hood it will get compiled into something equivalent to `memset`.

Comment: With `*responseData = 0;` only the first byte (of the 8000 uncleared) is written to. That makes the object a proper string with length zero. Subsequent string operations (`strcat()` especially) will do the right thing.

Comment: @pmg Maybe `responseData[0] = '\0';` would have been more clear.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: I agree about `a[0]` vs `*a` (and I'll try and remember to use the array form in the future); I'm not so sure about `'\0'` vs `0` -- thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not completely correct. You don't need to clear the whole `responseData` array - clearing its first byte is just enough:

```
 responseData[0] = 0;
```

As Gabriel Pellegrino notes in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048309/why-do-variables-declared-with-the-same-name-in-different-scopes-get-assigned-th/56048617#comment98739222_56048617), a more idiomatic expression is

```
 responseData[0] = '\0';
```

It explicitly defines a character via its code point of zero value, while the former uses an `int` constant zero. In both cases the right-side argument has type `int` which is implicitly converted (truncated) to `char` type for assignment. (Paragraph fixed thx to the pmg's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048309/why-do-variables-declared-with-the-same-name-in-different-scopes-get-assigned-th/56048617#comment98750414_56048617).)

You could know that from the `strcat` documentation:  the function **appends** its second argument string to the first one. If you need the very first chunk to get **stored** into the buffer, you want to append it to an empty string, so you need to ensure the string in the buffer is empty. That is, it consists of the terminating NUL character only. `memset`-ting the whole array is an overkill,  hence a waste of time.

Additionally, using a `strlen` on the array is asking for troubles. You can't know what the actual contents of the memory block allocated for the array is. If it was not used yet or was overwritten with some other data since your last use, it *may* contain *no* NUL character. Then `strlen` will run out of the array causing Undefined Behavior. And even if it returns successfuly, it will give you the string's length bigger than the size of the array. As a result `memset` will run out of the array, possibly overwriting some vital data!

Use **sizeof** whenever you `memset` an array!

```
memset(responseData, 0, sizeof(responseData));
```

**EDIT**

In the above I tried to explain how to fix the issue with your code, but I didn't answer your questions. Here they are:

1. **Why do variables (...) in different scopes get assigned the same memory addresses?**

In regard of execution each iteration of the `while(1) { ... }` loop indeed creates a new scope. However, each scope terminates before the new one is created, so the compiler reserves appropriate block of memory on the stack and the loop re-uses it in every iteration. That also simplifies a compiled code: every iteration is executed by exactly the same code, which simply jumps at the end to the beginning. All instructions within the loop that access local variables use exactly the same addressing (relative to the stack) in each iteration. So, each variable in the next iteration has precisely the same location in memory as in all previous iterations.

2. **I'm finding that I have to manually clear memory**

Yes, automatic variables, allocated on the stack, are *not initialized* in C by default. We always need to explicitly assign an initial value before we use it – otherwise the value is undefined and may be incorrect (for example, a floating-point variable can appear not-a-number, a character array may appear not terminated, an `enum` variable may have a value out of the enum's definition, a pointer variable may not point at a valid, accessible location, etc.).

3. **otherwise the contents (...) are just continuously appended**

This one was answered above.

4. **Coming from JavaScript, this was surprising**

Yes, JavaScript apparently *creates* new variables at the new scope, hence each time you get a brand new array – and it is empty. In C you just get the same area of a previously allocated memory for an automatic variable, and it's your responsibility to initialize it.

Additionally, consider two consecutive loops:

```
void test()
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        char buf1[10];
        sprintf(buf1, "%d", i);
    }

    for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
        char buf2[10];
        printf("%s\n", buf2);
    }
}
```

The first one prints a single-digit, character representation of five numbers into the character array, overwriting it each time - hence the last value of `buf1[]` (as a string) is `"4"`.

What output do you expect from the second loop? Generally speaking, we can't know what `buf2[]` will contain, and `printf`-ing it causes UB. However we *may suppose* the same set of variables (namely a single 10-items character array) from both disjoint scopes will get allocated the same way in the same part of a stack. If this is the case, we'll get a digit `4` as an output from a (formally uninitialized) array.

This result depends on the compiler construction and should be considered a coincidence. Do not rely on it as this is UB!

5. **Why wouldn't C just reset that memory behind the scenes?**

Because it's not told to. The language was created to compile to effective, compact code. It does as little 'behind the scenes' as possible. Among others things it does *not* do is *not* initializing automatic variables unless it's told to. Which means you need to add an explicit initializer to a local variable declaration or add an initializing instruction (e.g. an assignment) before the first use. (This does not apply to global, module-scope variables; those are initialized to zeros by default.)

In higher-level languages some or all variables are initialized on creation, but not in C. That's its feature and we must live with it – or just not use this language.

Comment: For idiomatic use, change to responseData[0] = '\0';

Comment: Also, the answer is OK if you're not dealing with char arrays as strings? I mean, what if this char arrays contains images, when '\0' isn't meaning the end of it?

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino Thank you for your comments. As for the first one: yes, you're right; `'\0'` is more explicit. I fixed it. For the latter: generally, `char[]` is an array of _characters_. Of course you can store other kind of data in it, we can `memcpy` any block of arbitrary data into a character array. Anyway, `strcpy` and `strcat` operate on _NUL-terminated strings_ of chars.

Comment: `'\0'` is an `int` absolutely 100% equal to `0`.

Comment: `char responseData[8000] = { 0 };` would be more idiomatic

Comment: @M.M Yes, but that unnecessarily initializes all the 8000 items of the array whilst it's actually needed to initialize just the first character.

Comment: @pmg Right. Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

With this line:

```
char responseData[8000];
```

You are saying to your compiler: Hey big C, give me a 8000 bytes chunk and name it responseData.

In runtime, if you don't specify, no one will ever clean or give you a "brand-new" chunk of memory. That means that the 8000 bytes chunk you get in every single execution can hold all the possible permutations of bits in this 8000 bytes. Something extraordinary that can happens, is that you're getting in every execution the same memory region and thus, the same bits in this 8000 bytes your big C gave to you in the first time. So, if you don't clean, you have the impression that you're using the same variable, but you're not! You're just using the same (never cleaned) memory region.

I'd add that it's part of the programmer's responsibilities to clean, if you need to, the memory you're allocating, in dynamic or static way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193066/discussion-on-answer-by-gabriel-pellegrino-why-do-variables-declared-with-the-sa).

Answer (score 3):

> Why would I want to declare a variable and have access to the memory contents of a variable declared in a different scope with the same name? Why wouldn't  C just reset that memory behind the scenes?

Objects with `auto` storage duration (i.e., block-scope variables) are not automatically initialized - their initial contents are *indeterminate*.  Remember that C is a product of the early 1970s, and errs on the side of runtime speed over convenience.  The C philosophy is that the programmer is in the best position to know whether something should be initialized to a known value or not, and is smart enough to do it themselves if needed.

While you're *logically* creating and destroying a new instance of `responseData` on each loop iteration, it turns out the same memory location is being reused each time through.  We like to think that space is allocated for each block-scope object as we enter the block and released as we leave it, but in practice that's (usually) not the case - space for *all* block-scope objects within a function is allocated on function entry, and released on function exit<sup>1</sup>.

Different objects in different scopes *may* map to the same memory behind the scenes.  Consider something like

```
void bletch( void )
{
  if ( some_condition )
  {
    int foo = some_function();
    printf( "%d\n", foo );
  } 
  else
  {
    int bar = some_other_function();
    printf( "%d\n", bar );
  }
```

It's impossible for both `foo` and `bar` to exist at the same time, so there's no reason to allocate separate space for both - the compiler will (usually) allocate space for one `int` object at function entry, and that space gets used for either `foo` or `bar` depending on which branch is taken.

So, what happens with `responseData` is that space for *one* 8000-character array is allocated on function entry, and that same space gets used for each iteration of the loop.  That's why you need to clear it out on each iteration, either with a `memset` call or with an initializer like

```
char responseData[8000] = {0};
```

---

1. As M.M points out in a comment, this isn't true for variable-length arrays (and potentially other variably modified types) - space for those *is* set aside as needed, although where that space is taken from isn't specified by the language definition.  For all other types, though, the *usual* practice is to allocate all necessary space on function entry.

Comment: " space for all block-scope objects within a function is allocated on function entry, and released on function exit."  - VLAs aren't allocated until execution reaches their definition